# Restricting GCP Load Balancer Traffic to App Engine behind IAP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have a Compute Engine instance with an API service running on it. In front of it is a Google Cloud Load Balancer. I do not want this API service exposed to the outside world.

I also have an App Engine Deployment that is behind Identity Aware Proxy. The application needs to be able to hit the API behind the load balancer.

What is the best practice here? What is the best way to enable this traffic and deal with authentication?

Comment: If you are planning to simply block your API, from reaching outside you can use firewall rules and for accessing it from a desired network you can use a VPN tunnel or Private service connect. Since you are trying to connect it to an App engine VM, we need to know few details like your application architecture and how you are planning to reach your application. Let's say if this a backend API you can use private IPs and use firewall rules for restricting their access and these private IPs will be used for communicating with your App engine instance